# Upgrading SpecFlow and SpecFlow+ resulting in 'SpecFlow.Plus.Runner.AssemblyHooks.cs could not be found' error

Tags: specflow

I have just attempted to upgrade my .net framework SpecFlow+ project from 3.0.225 to 3.5.14 for SpecFlow and from 3.0.391 to 3.5.8 for SpecFlow+ runner and I'm getting the following build error...

`'C:\Users\Matthew.OConnor\Source\Repos\selenium\Selenium.SEPA\obj\Debug\SpecFlow.Plus.Runner.AssemblyHooks.cs' could not be found`

The file isn't there but should it be there? Why might it not be there when I build?

I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio (16.8.2) and I have the following SpecFlow packages installed

- SpecFlow - 3.5.14
- SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic - 1.4.2
- SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation - 3.5.14
- SpecRun.Runner - 3.5.8
- SpecRun.SpecFlow.3-5-0 - 3.5.8 (This displays twice for some reason but was installed once)

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the problem was here, but creating a new project with the most up to date SpecFlow packages worked. I was then able to copy my files across